# Logo in all pages in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, open-source

I am new to wordpress and i have created blog using it.All blogs are on the home page.I have also upload the logo on home page and its visible only on home page so when user click on any of particular blog the logo is not visible there.

```
<div class="logo"> 
    <?php if ( get_theme_mod('himalayas_logo', '') != '') { ?> 
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php theme_logo(); ?></a> 
    <?php } ?> 
    <?php if (function_exists('the_custom_logo') && has_custom_logo( $blog_id = 0 )) { 
        himalayas_the_custom_logo();
    } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: @ Vasim Yes,I made changes in header.php but it worked only in home page.Its a built in theme.

Comment: <div class="logo">

      <?php if ( get_theme_mod('himalayas_logo', '') != '') { ?>
       <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php theme_logo(); ?></a>
      <?php } ?>

      <?php if (function_exists('the_custom_logo') && has_custom_logo( $blog_id = 0 )) {
       himalayas_the_custom_logo();
      } ?>

     </div>

Comment: @ Theme name is Himalaya

Comment: what is  site url

Comment: http://demo.ebiztechnolabs.com/

Comment: @Vasim click on any blog on home page and then you will be redirected to the detail page which has no logo on header.

Comment: @ No,that's not premium theme

Comment: ok please check this url you are followed step :

https://docs.themegrill.com/himalayas/

Comment: please check my answer

Comment: @ Vasim Thanks for your help

Comment: is it solved???

Comment: Yes made required changes but yet it didn't work

Comment: sorry I forget image tag

Comment: please check updated answer find solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove condition of check option value now code will be:

```
<div class="logo"> 
     <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
     <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo.png" alt="" />    
     </a> 

     </div>
```

**Finally Get answer**

revert all code to original modify code just go to

**Appreance->Theme->customize->Himalayas Header Options->Header Title/Tagline and Logo->select option "Header Logo Only"**

That's it

Comment: I have enable logo for all pages

Comment: did you upload change??